# Is there a word that can describe a student who goes out of his own way to help other students succeed?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

What's a word to describe a student who goes out of his own way to help others succeed? I'm trying to describe someone who often helps others with their work before doing his own and patiently explains concepts to someone who is confused during a lecture, just to give some examples.

I'm not looking for general words like team player, helpful, or kind; I'm trying to find more specific terms like didactic or cooperative. But I need a word that has much more of a positive connotation than cooperative.

Comment: Perhaps, _ideal_?

Comment: I think that gets the connotation of what I'm trying to talk about but not the denotation. Ideal seems too broad to describe this specific case I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though not teaching-specific perhaps  **Altruistic**

> unselfishly concerned for or devoted to the welfare of others (opposed to egoistic ). http://www.dictionary.com/browse/altruistic

Comment: Altruistic would certainly cover the OP's student-on-student situation, but it is not "teaching-specific", as you rightly point out. Therefore would not "study partner"  be more specific? Two words, I know, but this has become a feature of today's classrooms. For example: "I have an altruistic study partner who goes out of his way to mentor me in class and help me with my assignments".

Comment: I think my sample sentence above would be better without the word "altruistic". I should have deleted it within time allowed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean:

> **Magnanimous or Unstinting**

Magnanimous means: *generous or forgiving, especially towards a rival or less powerful person.* [[Source]](https://www.google.co.in/search?espv=2&q=define%20magnanimous&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjplrvylPrOAhXBLI8KHY3LDhEQ_SoIKTAA&biw=1366&bih=643)

and

Unstinting means: *given or giving without restraint; unsparing.* [[Source]](https://www.google.co.in/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=meaning%20of%20unstinting&oq=meaning%20of%20unstinting&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.4815j0j7)

Comment: I do think "unstinting" works better than "magnanimous" in the context of a classroom study buddy.